# Hive: select by alias and order by column name

Tags: sql, hive, sql-order-by, alias

Current query, which doesn't work:

```
select datetime as a
from coffee_chain
order by datetime;
```

Can some one know the reason.

Comment: Should we guess what your tables looks like and what the query looks like? :)

Comment: sry,bro. I forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
select datetime as a from coffee_chain order by a;
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1449

---

```
hive> create table coffee_chain (datetime int);
OK

hive> select datetime as a from coffee_chain order by datetime;
```

> ```
> FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid table alias or column reference 'datetime': (possible column names are: a)
> ```

```
hive> select datetime as a from coffee_chain order by a;
OK
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do u know why  can't use the column name in order by?

Comment: Seems like Hive limitation